# How to Migrate from Maven Web to Java Web? Specifically the files in the assemble folder

Tags: java, maven, web

I have a maven web project, and manually migrate it to a java web project, but the maven project contains a "assemble" folder, which contains 2 xml files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMkTF.png)

The structure of the file code is as follows:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

<id>theme</id>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>

<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/primefaces-barcelona-blue</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/META-INF/resources/primefaces-barcelona-blue</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

How can I complete the migration of these 2 files for my java web project? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about This but you have to try this and tell me if its successful . This may work if you are Eclipse user

Copy contents of fallowing path

Parent_directory_of_your_workspace/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps_or_webapps/your_web_app/WEB-INF/lib

Now past this contents in WEB-INF/lib of your project .
 Set the build path for all these libraries .
 Delete the pom.xml

If your project is properly published it must be under 
org.eclipse.wst.server.core in not under tmp0 search other folder you will find all library files deployed

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. I omitted the files from the "assemble" folder and I was able to generate the project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I do not explain the case correctly:

1. I have a web maven project, this project has the "assembles" folder and this folder has two xml files.
2. I have a new Java Web Application project, in this new project I migrate the functionality of the maven project, except the "assembles" folder.
3. I am using as NetBeans 8.1.

The new Java Web Application project does not work properly, and I need to migrate or integrate the "assembles" folder to review the project.

Th.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions.

I omitted the files from the "assemble" folder and I was able to generate the project correctly.